# How to clean garbage from CUDA in Pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I teached my neural nets and realized that even after torch.cuda.empty_cache() and gc.collect() my cuda-device memory is filled. In Colab Notebooks we can see the current variables in memory, but even I delete every variable and clean the garbage gpu-memory is busy.
I heard it's because python garbage collector can't work on cuda-device.
Please explain me, what should I do?

Comment: please see [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55322434/how-to-clear-cuda-memory-in-pytorch)

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
import gc
import torch
gc.collect()
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

Answer (score 3):

For me I have to delete the model before emptying the cache:

```
del model
gc.collect()
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

then you can check memory is freed using 'nvidia-smi'.